# Adding class with JQuery does not re-run @keyframe css animation in Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

Here is the page in question: http://alonzo.me/dev/pie/

And I am using the same basic markup that is shown here: https://phuu.net/2012/05/01/html-css-only-spinner.html

It is working great in every browser except safari for some reason.

I've been working on creating a css-only pie chart with @keyframe animations and setting animation-iteration-count to a decimal to run only a percentage of the animation. So I set a class for each percent (I'm not sure if there is a better way) like this:

```
.percent-1 .circle-fill,
.percent-1 .circle-fill-cover,
.percent-1 .circle-fill-cover-cover {
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 0.01;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 0.01;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: 0.01;
    animation-iteration-count: 0.01;
}
.percent-2 .circle-fill,
.percent-2 .circle-fill-cover,
.percent-2 .circle-fill-cover-cover {
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 0.02;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 0.02;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: 0.02;
    animation-iteration-count: 0.02;
}
```

...And so on from **.percent-0** to **.percent-100**

Yeah, it's a lot of classes.

For some reason Safari is not rotating the elements how it should be. In the snippet below I linked to an external css file because there were just way too many styles for a code snippet.

Any help with this would be much appreciated! :)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var percentageValue = $('#percentage-value');
var circleBG = $('.circle-background');

$('.jquery-area input[type="range"]').on("change mousemove", function() {
    var newClass = "percent-"+$(this).val();
    circleBG.attr('class', 'circle-background').addClass(newClass);
    $('.jquery-area input[type="number"]').val($(this).val());
});

$('.jquery-area input[type="number"]').bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
    var newClass = "percent-"+$(this).val();
    circleBG.attr('class', 'circle-background').addClass(newClass);    
    $('.jquery-area input[type="range"]').val($(this).val());
});

});
```

```css
.flex-center{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}
.jquery-area {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #BBB;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.jquery-area input {
    float: left;
}
.jquery-area p {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    height: 22;
    line-height: 22px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: -11px;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
.jquery-area input[type="range"] {
    height: 22px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline;
}
.jquery-area input[type="number"] {
    height: 26px;
    width: 40px;
    padding-left: 3px;
}

.circle-background {
 position: relative;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 background: #06A;
 border-radius: 100%;
 -webkit-mask-box-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center,ellipse cover,rgba(0,0,0,1) 68%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 69.5%);
 -moz-mask-box-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center,ellipse cover,rgba(0,0,0,1) 68%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 69.5%);
 -o-mask-box-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center,ellipse cover,rgba(0,0,0,1) 68%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 69.5%);
 mask-box-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center,ellipse cover,rgba(0,0,0,1) 68%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 69.5%);
 overflow: hidden;
}
.circle-fill, .circle-fill-cover, .circle-fill-cover-cover {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
 border-width: 50px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: transparent;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.circle-fill {
 border-top-color: #09F;
 -webkit-animation: circle-fill-animation 2s linear;
 -moz-animation: circle-fill-animation 2s linear;
 -o-animation: circle-fill-animation 2s linear;
 animation: circle-fill-animation 2s linear;
}
.circle-fill-cover {
 content: "";
 border-top-color: #06A;
 -webkit-animation: circle-fill-cover-animation 2s linear;
 -moz-animation: circle-fill-cover-animation 2s linear;
 -o-animation: circle-fill-cover-animation 2s linear;
 animation: circle-fill-cover-animation 2s linear;
}
.circle-fill-cover-cover {
 content: "";
 border-right-color: #09F;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-animation: circle-fill-cover-cover-animation 2s linear;
 -moz-animation: circle-fill-cover-cover-animation 2s linear;
 -o-animation: circle-fill-cover-cover-animation 2s linear;
 animation: circle-fill-cover-cover-animation 2s linear;
}

/* This needs to go at the end */
.circle-fill, .circle-fill-cover, .circle-fill-cover-cover {
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://alonzo.me/dev/pie/animation-percentages.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="flex-center">
  <div class="circle-background percent-85">
    <span class="circle-fill"></span>
    <span class="circle-fill-cover"></span>
    <span class="circle-fill-cover-cover"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-center">
 <div class="jquery-area">
  <p>Percentage:</p>
  <br>
  <input type="range" name="points" min="0" max="100" value="85"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="85"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow in Chrome works like a charm... but my safari crash after the animation !!! WHY?

Comment: Can you please put your JS too?

Comment: Woops! Yeah I guess I forgot that :P

Comment: I've made a test, but my Safari still crash, can you check it with yours? http://www.vixed.it/st/35384307

Comment: I tried it, and it still doesn't work for me as well. I had a similar thing happening in firefox before I created browser prefixed -moz-transform selectors for rotating it.

Comment: I tried a lot of stuff, but I get lost. may be I'll try tomorrow. anyway I found something that can became useful to you: http://kottenator.github.io/jquery-circle-progress/ let me know.

Comment: @Vixed That is probably a better way to accomplish the same thing and much more, but I really wanted a pure CSS solution first, just to see if it could be done and it's so close!

Comment: I agree with you, but css animation and compatibility with browsers... you know..